# AngularJS ng-repeat not updating DOM nodes when element is inserted dynamically

Tags: angularjs

`ng-repeat` is not updating DOM nodes when we use same controller name in different area.

```
<div ng-controller="customer">
    <div ng-repeat="number in numberArray">
         {{number}}                                     
   </div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="customer">
    <div ng-repeat="number in numberArray">
         {{number}}                                     
   </div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="ncDialText"/>
   <button ng-click="add()"/>
</div>

myApp.controller('customer',function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.numberArray =[];
       $scope.add = function() { 
          $scope.numberArray.push($scope.ncDialText);
       }    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the ng-controller creates a new instance of each controller so the scope is different in the two ng-repeat directives.

One way to fix that is to have a controller that covers both ng-repeats

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customer">
    <div >
        <div ng-repeat="number in numberArray">
             {{number}}                                     
       </div>
    </div>

    <div >
        <div ng-repeat="number in numberArray">
             {{number}}                                     
       </div>
       <input type="text" ng-model="ncDialText"/>
        <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The other option is to use a service to store the data like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enlightenmedia/zvhgfcau/2/)

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('customerService', function() {

    var _self = this;

    _self.numberArray = [];

    return {
        numberArray: _self.numberArray
    }
});

myApp.controller('customer',function($scope, $http, customerService) {
       $scope.numberArray = customerService.numberArray;
       $scope.add = function() { 
           customerService.numberArray.push($scope.ncDialText);
       }    
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="customer">
        <div ng-repeat="number in numberArray">
             {{number}}                                     
       </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="customer">
        <div ng-repeat="number in numberArray">
             {{number}}                                     
       </div>
       <input type="text" ng-model="ncDialText"/>
        <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```